# How to call a function inside a main function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function chart(){
       Barchart();
       Linechart();
       function Barchart(){
       }
       function Linechart(){
       }
}
```

`Chart()` is main parent function. Inside I have two chart functions. I have to call only line chart.
`Chart();` will execute both barchart and linechart. 
but I need to call only line chart.

Comment: you need to follow proper oops pattern here to call the nested `Linechart` method only. Or you can pass the params at the time of call to `chart('line') or chart('bar')` to execute them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Both will execute in the order given. You need to provide some sort of selection. Either using an if/then or some other way.

```
If(myChecbox.isSelected){
barchart();}
else{
linechart();
}
```

Ask yourself, what is it that is making the choice? Let me know what you come up with. You will need to place the called functions outside of your method...as stated in the others post.

Answer (score 2):

I know only object function can call for one specific function ..

```
var chart = {
       Barchart : function(){
        alert('');
       },
       Linechart : function(){
        alert('');
       }
}
chart.Barchart();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the inner function to be executed,

```
function outer() { 
    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
    inner(); // call it
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should do this so that you have good control on your function calling or you directly Linechart also return instead of init

```
var chart = (function () {

        var Barchart = function () {
            console.log("bar chart");
        };
        var Linechart = function () {
            console.log("line chart");
        };
        var init = function () {
            Linechart();
        }
        return {
            init: init
            //you can retrun Barchart or Linechart which you want to access publically
        }
    })();
    chart.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

The scope of this functions is only the `chart()` function, so they are not accessible outside, unless you give them out from inside `chart()` somehow, like by returning them.

Comment: I am expecting a way like this.

function charts() {
     this.LoadBarchart = function(){
     }
    this.LoadLineChart = function() {
    }
}

var charts = new charts();
charts.LoadLineChart();

Comment: @Lux call to `chart();` will invoke the inner functions.First 2 lines of it are invoking them.

Comment: @techie_28 there has been an edit to the question. I will edit as well. @ Subash its not possible without editing the `chart()` function, like you could call it with an `false` argument and then just return the other functions. But this is nothing I would recommend. But you *have* to call it to get the functions out.

Answer (score 0):

after your edit just remove the first call to `Barchart()`

Answer (score 0):

Although less common, nesting functions this way is possible. It's a method called currying. Your function Linechart() is scoped within chart(), so at the moment, it can only be called there. In order to make it available elsewhere, you'll need to place it out with the function so the scope is broadened. Something along the lines of:

```
   function Linechart(){
     alert("Line called!");
   }

function chart(){

   function Barchart(){
     alert("Bar called!");
   }

    Barchart();
    Linechart();
}

chart(); 
// Line chart on it's own
Linechart();
```

This will mean that when you call chart(), both Linechart() and Barchart() are called, but you'll also be able to call Linechart() on its own.

Comment: his question is different & first 2 lines of the `chart()` function are actually invoking the functions

Comment: Ah, looks like the original post was edited. The calls weren't there previously! Makes more sense now, I'll edit my response.

Answer (score 0):

i hope these will be helpful.

```
function chart() {
function Barchart()
{
    alert('Barchart');
}
function Linechart() 
{
    alert('Linechart');
}
Barchart();  
Linechart();
}
chart();
```